# How to add If-Else Conditional statement, to an element with an event listener?

Tags: javascript, html

As I am using [Smooth-Scrollbar Plugin by idiotWu](https://github.com/idiotWu/smooth-scrollbar). As to install the script, we need to mark the whole content under the `<main>` tag, just after the `<body>` tag, so the whole page is scroll-able, so we can't detect the scroll position using the standard function.

I want to set a condition, using If and Else statement, stating, If `<main class="wrapper">` or its child `<div class="scroll-content">`, has `transform: translate3d(0px, -400px, 0px)`, add id fixed to the header, else remove id fixed from the header, all that using an event listener. This will make the header appear on the top as fixed only on-scroll, that to when it reaches to `left: 0px; top: -400px;`.

Below is the DOM and the script which listens to the offset.x and offset.y of `<main class="wrapper">` and sets the same value of offset.x and offset.y to the `<header id="fixed">` which keeps the header on top always, whatsoever.

Here is the DOM

```
<body>
  <main class="wrapper">
    <div class="root-content">
      <header id="fixed">
        <h2>My Header</h2>
      </header>
      <section>
      </section>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Here is the script

```
// -- Plugin Initialization -- //
Scrollbar.use(OverscrollPlugin);
Scrollbar.init(document.querySelector('.wrapper'));

// -- Fixed Header -- //
var main_scrollbar = Scrollbar.init(document.querySelector('.wrapper'));
 main_scrollbar.addListener(function(status) {
   var offset = status.offset;

   fixed.style.left = offset.x + 'px';
   fixed.style.top = offset.y + 'px';
});
```

This is how the above script works. It picks the transform values from the `<div class="scroll-content">` and applies the value i.e. `style="left: 0px; top: 400px;"` to the `<header id="fixed">`, so it remains on the top.

[image]

I want to make the header appear on the top or make it fixed only when the `<div class="scroll-content">` has  `transform: translate3d(0px, -400px, 0px)`. But using the script above the header is always fixed or sticked, so in that case a conditional if else statement is required to modify the above script, so the header is added with the `id="fixed"` only when `<div class="scroll-content">` has  `transform: translate3d(0px, -400px, 0px)`.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/ToxifiedM/pen/WNrozbr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find the `transform` property from `style` attribute in your element

```
element.style.transform
```

Then use a regex to find if matches

```
/translate3d\(0px\, -400px\, 0px\)/.test(element.style.transform)
```

That will give `true` or `false` so you can use in any if statement.

Edit: Perhaps, this may be what you're looking for

```
var sc = document.querySelector(".scroll-content");
//select the scroll-content element
let translateString = sc.style.transform.split(", ")[1].replace("px","");
//split and replace the transform string to keep only Y axis value
let translateNum = parseInt(translateString);
//Parse the string to int number
if(translateNum <= -400) return false;
//compare and return if condition does not match
```

So your status function would end like this:

```
function(status) {

  let sc = document.querySelector(".scroll-content");
  let translateString = sc.style.transform.split(", ")[1].replace("px","");
  let translateNum = parseInt(translateString);
  if(translateNum <= -400) return false;

  var offset = status.offset;
  fixed.style.left = offset.x + 'px';
  fixed.style.top = offset.y + 'px';
}
```

Edit 2: What you ask is to set an attribute on condition. You may apply this (following previous function)

```
let header = document.querySelector(".root-content > header");
if (translateNum <= -400){ 
  header.setAttribute("id", "fixed");
}
else{
  header.removeAttribute("id");
}
```

I hope that helps you out.

Comment: As we need to listen for continuous changes, an even listener is required, can you markup a snippet or CodePen for me for the same? If its not a problem, obviously.

Comment: I assume you want to listen to a scroll event, right?

Comment: Yup, but standard function will not work, because of the plugin, that's why I had added an event listener to the `<main class="wrapper">` because that is the scrollbar, just check the CodePen for clarifications, https://codepen.io/ToxifiedM/pen/WNrozbr

Comment: I did some test and updated the answer, check it out.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your effort, but this is what I am getting, after I imply your set of code, https://codepen.io/ToxifiedM/pen/oNbBYJE, and its doing completely opposite of what I need it to do, just have a look.

Comment: Can we add `id="fixed"` to `<header>` only when the `scroll-content` reaches to `transform: translate3d(0px, -400px, 0px)` by listening to `<main class="wrapper">`, that will solve the issue, I just have no idea how to proceed with it.

Comment: Thanks for throwing some light, I however got a brief idea, its pretty clean though.